# Files.Copy throws java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException using Java in linux

Tags: java, linux, file-copying

```
public void copyFiles(){
    File source = new File("/home/anil/FileLocation/Source/test1.text");
    File destination = new File("/home/anil/FileLocation/Destination/"+ source.getName());

    try {
        Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does source.getName() return *exactly*?

Comment: Also, why do you just make a file to overwrite it?

Comment: Can you manually copy it on the command line? Can you please add pieces of the stacktrace of your exception?

Comment: [err] java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/anil/FTPLocation/Source/test1.text
[err]  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
[err]  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
[err]  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
[err]  at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:524)
[err]  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:253)

Comment: source.getName() to keep the file name same to destination folder

Comment: I am try to copy the file using Java Code. I have done this in Windows OS using File source = new File("D:/FileLocation/Source/text1.text");

Comment: Getting exception while getting source.toPath()